# Maps API is there a way to get available routes from A to B when they are the same?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

So I want to find different walking routes where the start and end destination is the same. So If I as a user choose 5km, maps would show me routes that are about 5km long and start and ends at the same location. I have looked through the (messy) maps apis but haven't managed to find any endpoints for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that by adding waypoints. So for a 5km walk you could generate a random point within 2.5 km of your start/end point and add it as a waypoint when generating directions.

Edit:

In addition you may try using the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical) in the Google Maps API. There is a computeOffset function which returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north). This way you can add some waypoints relative to the start/end point. Or in close proximity to the random first waypoint.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

Comment: Ah yes I did look into that. I don't know if that part of the API differs from google/maps, beacuse if you specify the same start and endpoint and then add a random waypoint somewhere, it will show that the fastest way is going to the waypoint and back again, the same way but in reverse.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. In that case add two waypoints so the routes goes from start point to waypoint 1 then to waypoint 2 and then back to the start point.

Comment: Adding waypoints in close proximity to each other kinda works, but I can't see how I could do that in Code. Have to think this over.

Comment: Try using the Geometry library in the Google Maps API. There is a computeOffset function which returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north). This way you can add some waypoints relative to the start/end point. Or in close proximity to the random first waypoint.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#spherical

Comment: Hmm that is possible I think. Will be quite alot of calls though, but it should work. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer as well. Could you mark it as the answer please. Thank you.